# Benefits of running apache as a service?

Tags: apache, xampp

I've just installed XAMPP and just wondering what are the benefits of running Apache as a service?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the benefits is that when installed as a service is that you can limit the privileges (directories read/write access, network access, this means better security of course) of the account that runs it (the default is the `LocalSystem` account on Windows, you can find more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677973%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

And as admin pointed out, you can also keep the service running without you being logged in all the time.

Answer (score 5):

The benefits of a service in general (on Windows) :

- It can automatic start at **System Logon**
- Start and stop not related to a specific user session
- Run in Background
- Can run under a *special account* (LocalSystem, Network Service)
- From Vista/Server 2008 onwards run in Session 0 (Isolation)

If you use apache only for developing purpose you can avoid to install it as service and run it when needed directly from your user session, in a production enviroment is highly recommended to install and run it as service ...

Answer (score 2):

-Don't have to start it after each boot.
-If you log off the server continues running.

If you will use the server all the time, set it as a service... If not, just start it when you need it to keep the resourses free.